# Track memory allocations on Linux

Tags: rhel, linux-kernel, logs, memory

Is there a way to track memory allocations performed by kernel? I've found [an article, where memory allocations are tracked in kernel log](https://elinux.org/images/a/a8/Controlling_Linux_Memory_Fragmentation_and_Higher_Order_Allocation_Failure-_Analysis,_Observations_and_Results.pdf) (I guess). Here is how it looks like:

```
[ 3830.215613] [HIGHERORDER_DEBUG] : __alloc_pages_nodemask is called by process <PID = 1168, NAME = Xorg> !!!
```

Perhaps it is some custom kernel build...

Is there a way I can track memory allocations in such way?
Perhaps there are some tools for that? I'm using RHEL7.

Comment: Not to insult your intelligence, but you do realize the gigantic performance impact this would have, don't you?

Comment: Thanks, @ajeh, for comment. Sure, I do, I need it only for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a full answer, but may give you a direction to start looking.

This is a RAM forensics framework that may give you some tools to track. I've only used it a little bit, but this will give you a kernel module that will give you a lot of access to what is going on in the RAM.

http://www.volatilityfoundation.org/releases

Actually...  I also found this article that has some boot-time options (and some more details) for logging kernel memory allocation. Maybe that will do it for you?

```
trace_event=kmem:kmalloc,kmem:kmem_cache_alloc,kmem:kfree,kmem:kmem_cache_free
```

https://elinux.org/Kernel_dynamic_memory_analysis

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kevin! I'll try with your advice and let you know if it helps.

Comment: Adding `trace_event` boot option gave all that I wanted to get. Thanks @Kevin.